# MySQL pdo and legacy

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is there a way by which I can make the result set returned by PDO same as the data set returned by the legacy `mysql` functions?

Actually, all the files in my application call a function to execute any SQL query. Currently that function uses old `mysql` functions. I want to change it to PDO in that single function, effectively changing to PDO over the whole application.

Hence, I need a way so that the format of the result coming out is the same as the old `mysql` functions.

Comment: Show your legacy code.

Comment: Do you mean to get a mysql resource instead of a `PDOStatement`? What'd be the point, if you'll then need to edit all the subsequent function calls?

Comment: Note that using `PDO` to execute queries in a function would imply _either_ a global `PDO` instance, a closure instance or _constructing a PDO instance on each function call_. Perhaps it'd serve you better to replace the function with an object. Because objects can hold state, there's no need to reconnect to the DB each time you want to execute a query. As a quick fix, you could make it a fugly static method, and a static property, holding the PDO instance. But keep working on the object. Also `mysqli_*` is closer to `mysql_*` in terms of it returning result resources and the like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the *result set resource* returned by `mysql_query`, then: no. Resources are specific to the extension that defines them and are meaningless to anything else. PDO returns an object, `mysql_query` a resource; that's apples and oranges.

If you mean an array you'd build with `mysql_fetch_assoc` and `PDOStatement::fetch`, then: of course, you can make them look identical if you bother to do so.